# std::invoke_result<F, Args...> does not seem to give a const type

Tags: c++, c++11, c++17, metaprogramming

I'd like to start with a simplified example:

```
const bool Foo() { return false; }
bool Bar() { return false; }

int main() {
  std::cout << std::is_same<const bool, std::invoke_result_t<decltype(Foo)>>::value << std::endl;
  std::cout << std::is_same<bool, std::invoke_result_t<decltype(Foo)>>::value << std::endl;
  std::cout << std::is_same<bool, std::invoke_result_t<decltype(Bar)>>::value << std::endl;
}
```

I expected `1 0 1` but the result was `0 1 1`.

Is this expected? If so, is this different from compiler to compiler, or determined by the C++ standard?

My understanding was we can still return `const T` but it just does not make much difference/does not make sense since `C++11`. Thus, I thought the return type is still `const T` (`const bool` here) and the compiler would warn me, which does not appear to be the case. I'd like to understand what is going on.

Comment: https://godbolt.org/z/xeYYnjea1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`std::invoke_result` does not give you the declared return type of the function. It gives you the `decltype` that an `INVOKE` expression, i.e. a function call expression in this case, would have with the given argument types. That is specified essentially exactly like this (with a bit more technical wording) in the standard.

A function call expression of a function returning by-value (instead of by-reference) is a prvalue expression. If a prvalue expression is of non-class type, it has its `const`-qualifier always stripped. There is no difference between a `const` and non-`const` non-class prvalue in the language.

So that is why you don't get a `const`. `const` on a function returning a non-class type by-value is essentially pointless and compilers will warn you about that with warnings enabled. The only effect the `const` has here is to change the type of the function. There is no difference in actual calls to the function.

Even `const` on a class type returned by-value is mostly useless. There are only few special cases where it makes sense (e.g. to disallow calling modifying member functions directly on the call expression), but also comes with significant issues (i.e. potentially disabling move semantics). This was more common in early C++, but since C++11 it is also only seldom used.